# How to sort an arrayList when the datatype is not a string Java?

Tags: java

I have an arrayList that stores objects. Each object contains string and integer. How can I sort this arrayList alphabetically based on the object's string? (I tried Collections.sort(arrayList's name) but since the arrayList's data type isn't a string, it won't sort.)

Comment: Are you sure that searching [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=sort+objects+java) on a search engine got you no solutions?

Comment: Yes! :) I was just wondering if there were other solutions/approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a custom Comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list,(o1,o2)->o1.getString().compareTo(o2.getString());
```

or implement the Comparable interface:

```
public class YourClass implements Comparable<YourClass>{
   ...
   @Override
   public int compareTo(YourClass other){
      //TODO: Error handling
      return this.getString().compareTo(other.getString();
   }
}
//and then:
//Collections.sort(list);
```